# Get formatted date at Eloquent results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, date-format

Considering that the model is

```
class Cota extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['status','user_id','produto_id','numero','arquivo','updated_at'];

    protected $dates = [
        'updated_at',
    ];

    //protected $dateFormat = 'd/m/Y';
}
```

And considering the query:

```
$cotas = DB::table('cotas')->join('produtos','produtos.id','=','cotas.produto_id')->join('users','users.id','=','cotas.user_id')->select('cotas.id','produtos.titulo as produto','cotas.numero','cotas.arquivo','users.name','cotas.status','cotas.updated_at','produtos.valor')->get();
```

When I get only one instance, like:

```
$cota = Cota::find(6517);
```

I can do this:

```
$cota->updated_at->format('d/m/Y');
```

But in the query above, the results come always with the traditionl date format used by Mysql.
How do I get the results with the ('d/m/Y') format? I have to use a raw query? Is that the only way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always user DB::raw in Select statement.

```
$cotas = DB::table('cotas')
    ->join('produtos','produtos.id','=','cotas.produto_id')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','cotas.user_id')
    ->select([
        'cotas.id',
        'produtos.titulo as produto',
        'cotas.numero',
        'cotas.arquivo',
        'users.name',
        'cotas.status', 
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(cotas.updated_at, "%d/%m/%Y"') as updated_at,
        'produtos.valor'
    ])
    ->get();

// Or Else You can always loop over your collection when displaying data / using that data.
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is a solution. But I was wondering if I can get the same results using a mutator or something like this.

Comment: @Fabiano Yes, to use DB::table you have to use DB::raw. You can use casts if you are using an eloquent model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use date casting like so

```php
protected $casts = [
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:d/m/Y',
];
```

This is only useful when the model is serialized to an array or JSON according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting).

Comment: Ok, thanks, but even considering that 'updated_at' field already is a Carbon derived?

Comment: Laravel takes care of that automatically, but when you cast it like that, it overrides it. So it's not already 'Carbon'.